# React native - How do I start a timer, then navigate a different screen, then come back and have the timer still in sync with its original countdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The title really says it all. I've seen some questions about how to keep a component from un-mounting, but I'm not sure that's exactly what I need (or at least not all that I need).
I  want it to continue counting when I go to a different screen in the app.
Can anyone tell me how to approach this?
Thanks

Comment: Also having this issue. Did you find a resolution?